# How to create an rgb GeoTIFF file raster from bands using the GDAL python module?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, rgb

I'm trying to create a new raster from three bands (rgb). I got the script mostly from [here.](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html) I can create a single band raster with no problems, but I'm having trouble inputting a tree band numpy array. I'm greeted with this error message when I attempt it.

> ValueError: expected array of dim 2

If I try to create a three band GeoTIFF image I end up with a *grey,alpha,alpha* image instead of an *rgb* image, nor am I able to populate these with my three-dimensional numpy array. The following script works for creating a greyscale raster. with three bands as *grey,alpha,alpha*.

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr
import os
import io
import numpy as np

def array2raster(newRasterfn,rasterOrigin,pixelWidth,pixelHeight,array,format,spatialRef):

    bands = array.shape[0]
    cols = array.shape[1]
    rows = array.shape[2]

    originX = rasterOrigin[0]
    originY = rasterOrigin[1]

    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)
    outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, bands,gdal.GDT_UInt16,options = ['PHOTOMETRIC=RGB', 'PROFILE=GeoTIFF',])
    outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))

    for band in range(bands):
        outRaster.GetRasterBand(band+1).WriteArray(array[band,:,:])
        outRaster.GetRasterBand(band+1).FlushCache()
    outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
    outRasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(spatialRef)
    outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())


def get_rgb_bands():
    source = gdal.Open("C:\\RGBtest.tif")

    red = source.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
    green = source.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray()
    blue = source.GetRasterBand(3).ReadAsArray()

    #rgbOutput = source.ReadAsArray() #Easier method
    rgbOutput = np.zeros((3,16,16), 'uint16')

    rgbOutput[0,...] = red
    rgbOutput[1,...] = green
    rgbOutput[2,...] = blue

    #Clear so file isn't locked
    source = None
    return rgbOutput

exampleRGB = get_rgb_bands()

exampleOutput = "C:\\ExampleOutput.tif"
rasterOrigin=[0,0]

array2raster(exampleOutput,rasterOrigin,1, 1,exampleRGB,'GTiff',3879) 

createdFile = gdal.Open("C:\\ExampleOutput.tif")

print 'old file info:'+gdal.Info(source)
print 'new file info:'+gdal.Info(createdFile)

createdFile = None

exampleOutput = None
```

EDIT: Luke answered this question perfectly I have updated the code to reflect a working example to output a 16-bit rgb raster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the colour [interpretation](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdalconst-module.html) for most rasters using [Band.SetColorInterpretation](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal.Band-class.html), i.e

```
outband.SetColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_RedBand)
```

However, this is only understood by GDAL based software.  To specifically create a GeoTIFF with an RGB baseline [PhotometricInterpretation tag](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/photometricinterpretation.html) (this is not a GDAL tag, but part of the TIFF spec) pass a `PHOTOMETRIC=RGB` option to the [GeoTIFF driver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html) when creating the raster:

```
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GeoTIFF')
options = ['PHOTOMETRIC=RGB', 'PROFILE=GeoTIFF']
outRaster = driver.Create(filepath, cols, rows, bands, datatype, options=options)
```

You're also trying to write 3 bands to a single band:

(`outRaster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(etc...)`)

Get used to having your arrays in [bands, rows, cols] order not [cols, rows, bands] as this is how gdal arranges them when reading into a numpy array.  Then you need to loop through the array "bands" and write each of them to the raster bands:

```
bands = array.shape[0]
for band in range(bands):
    outRaster.GetRasterBand(band+1).WriteArray( array[band, :, :] )
```

Try something like:

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr
import os
import io
import numpy as np

def array2raster(newRasterfn,rasterOrigin,pixelWidth,pixelHeight,array,format='GTiff'):

    bands = array.shape[0]
    rows = array.shape[1]
    cols = array.shape[2]
    originX = rasterOrigin[0]
    originY = rasterOrigin[1]
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)
    #Here is where I assign three bands to the raster with int 3
    options = ['PHOTOMETRIC=RGB', 'PROFILE=GeoTIFF']
    outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, bands, gdal.GDT_UInt16, options=options)
    outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
    #outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
    #outband.WriteArray(array)
    for band in range(bands):
        outRaster.GetRasterBand(band+1).WriteArray( array[band, :, :] )

    outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
    outRasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(6962)
    outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())

    return outRaster


def example_rgb_creation():
    source = gdal.Open("C:\\RGBtest.tif")
    rgb_array = source.ReadAsArray()

    return rgb_array

exampleRGB = example_rgb_creation()
exampleOutput = "C:\\Temp\\ExampleOutput.tif"
rasterOrigin=[0,0]

outRaster = array2raster(exampleOutput,rasterOrigin,1, 1,exampleRGB)

outRaster.GetRasterBand(1).SetColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_RedBand)
outRaster.GetRasterBand(2).SetColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_GreenBand)
outRaster.GetRasterBand(3).SetColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_BlueBand)

del outRaster
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got to create a tiff file but it is unreadable now. I populated separate rgb bands and then populated them from separate rgb arrays. But I think that I'm not writing the actual driver correctly. I don't understand how the driver gets the bands.

Comment: I tried different ways but the bands still stay as *grey, alpha, alpha* instead of *r,g,b*

Comment: Your edit made everything clear, except that writing to a 16-bit GeoTIFF still creates bands as *grey, alpha, alpha* instead of *r,g,b*. If I write *gdal.GDT_Byte* thus writing an *8-bit* raster, everything works beautifully (although clamped to 256 colors). The problem is that I absolutely need the extra dynamic range, since the raster will be used by a different program in the future.

Comment: The raster I'm outputting is a [normalmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping) for another program. The channels matter very much, and I need to use georeferenced coordinates. I found this [documentation about designating specific color-types](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_8h.html#a18d4e3dfbc97c1fddab692eabb3c5a24) but I'm unsure how to assign this data to the driver?

Comment: The other program I am using is already compiled to work with RGB color channels. Currently Gdal outputs three channels as *greyscale, alpha, alpha*. The program interprets this as *greyscale = red, greyscale = green, greyscale = blue, alpha1 = transparency, alpha2 = nothing.* I can see the channels assigned in Photoshop.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. The whole concept of raster is quite new to me. I'm more accustomed with bitmaps and channels. I would like to create a 16-bit bitmap with rgb channels.

Comment: gdalinfo says the same thing in my case. The problem is that if I open the file in notepad it says.


    <Item name="COLORINTERP" sample="0" role="colorinterp">Red</Item>


    <Item name="COLORINTERP" sample="1" role="colorinterp">Undefined</Item>


    <Item name="COLORINTERP" sample="2" role="colorinterp">Undefined</Item>

Comment: OMG. It worked. I really can't thank you enough. It now outputs a 16-bit rgb. Where were you able to find the documentation to figure it out. I have a very hard time finding these settings?

Comment: Yeah, it does spell it out failry explicitly in the *PHOTOMETRIC* section. Now I feel kinda stupid.

Comment: The trouble with GDAL documentation is that the info is easy to find if you know where to look in the first place...

Comment: @user2856, I ave a question. What means three  GRB data? It is an elevation data or real scanned image?

Comment: @BenchVue don't ask me, [ask everybody](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).